# How this bit conversion going on?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

```
 private int ControlDecode(byte b)
    {
        int itype = -1;
        int ipacekttype = b & 0xF0;
        switch (ipacekttype)
        {
            case 0x40:
                if ((b & 0x0F) != 0x0F)
                    itype = 0x45;
                else
                    itype = 0x4F;
                break;
            case 0x50:
                itype = 0x45;
                break;
            case 0x00:
                itype = 0x00;
                break;
            case 0x80:
                itype = 0x89;
                break;
            case 0x90:
                itype = 0x89;
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
        return itype;
    }
```

If b=51, ipacekttype=48( according to code execution)
    but theoratically when masking we should get 50 as answer
   can anyone explain me how (b & 0xF0) works here please?

Comment: "when masking we should get 50" - How do you figure? decimal 51 = 0011 0011, bitwise and with 0xF0 (which is 1111 0000) = 0011 0000, which is indeed decimal 48.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank yu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing decimal notation and hex notation. When you say `b=51`, it appears that `51` is decimal, so `bn=0x33` in hex. This explains why `ipacekttype=48` - again, in decimal, because it's `ipacekttype=0x30` in hex, i.e. exactly what it is supposed to be after masking `0x33` with `0xF0`.